# Unable to install "Runner" on real device

Tags: xcode, flutter, apple-developer

I'm using Flutter 3.0.4.

I run my app on my iPhone connected by USB, and I got this error:

[image]

The details button shows this:

[image]

I'm sure about that there is not duplicate bundle ID on apple developer or my phone.

Comment: I also have this problem. Haven't you solved it yet?

Comment: @mirjafarabedi I solved this. Just open your Xcode, and press shift+command+k to clean build folder. You can see "Clean finished" on the top of Xcode.

Comment: Does it work on a simulator?

Comment: @koen Yes, I also get error on simulator.

Comment: same issue done everything but didnt resolved yet any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press shift+command+k to clean build folder.
2. Check your info.plist and AppFrameworkInfo.plist, **bundle identifier** should not be the same.